# Printing shell script doesn't print anything

Tags: bash, shell, permission-denied, procmail

I'm trying to create a print service von my raspberry pi. The idea is to have a pop3 account for print jobs where I can sent PDF files and get them printed at home. Therefore I set up fetchmail & rarr; procmail & rarr; uudeview to collect the emails (using a whitelist), extract the documents and save them to `/home/pi/attachments/`. Up to this point everything is working.

To get the files printed I wanted to set up a shell script which I planned to execute via a cronjob every minute. That's where I'm stuck now since I get "permission denied" messages and nothing gets printed at all with the script while it works when executing the commands manually.

This is what my script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
fetchmail                 # gets the emails, extracts the PDFs to ~/attachments
wait $!                   # takes some time so I have to wait for it to finish
FILES=/home/pi/attachments/*
for f in $FILES; do       # go through all files in the directory
   if  $f == "*.pdf"      # print them if they're PDFs
   then
      lpr -P ColorLaserJet1525 $f
   fi
   sudo rm $f             # delete the files
done;
sudo rm /var/mail/pi      # delete emails
```

After the script is executed I get the following Feedback:

```
1 message for print@MYDOMAIN.TLD at pop3.MYDOMAIN.TLD (32139 octets).
Loaded from /tmp/uudk7XsG: 'Test 2' (Test): Stage2.pdf part 1   Base64
Opened file /tmp/uudk7XsG
procmail: Lock failure on "/var/mail/pi.lock"
reading message print@MYDOMAIN.TLD@SERVER.HOSTER.TLD:1 of 1 (32139 octets) flushed
mail2print.sh: 6: mail2print.sh: /home/pi/attachments/Stage2.pdf: Permission denied
```

The email is fetched from the pop3 account, the attachement is extracted and appears for a short moment in `~/attachements/` and then gets deleted. But there's no printout.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What user is actually executing the script (in other words, what user are you executing `crontab` as)? Is it the same user that you can run the script with manually?

Comment: It's the same user who executes crontab and who runs the script. The problem was that even if running the script I ran into the errors. However executing the single commands (fetchmail, lpr -P ColorLaserJet1525 test.pdf, sudo rm test.pdf, sudo rm /var/mail/pi) worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if  $f == "*.pdf"
```

should be

```
if  [[ $f == *.pdf ]]
```

Also I think

```
FILES=/home/pi/attachments/*
```

should be quoted:

```
FILES='/home/pi/attachments/*'
```

Suggestion:

```
#!/bin/bash
fetchmail                      # gets the emails, extracts the PDFs to ~/attachments
wait "$!"                      # takes some time so I have to wait for it to finish
shopt -s nullglob              # don't present pattern if no files are matched
FILES=(/home/pi/attachments/*)
for f in "${FILES[@]}"; do                              # go through all files in the directory
    [[ $f == *.pdf ]] && lpr -P ColorLaserJet1525 "$f"  # print them if they're PDFs
done
sudo rm -- "${FILES[@]}" /var/mail/pi         # delete files and emails at once
```

Comment: +1 for fixing the conditional. While there's no harm in quoting `/home/pi/attachments/*`, it is _not necessary_ - pathname expansion is _not_ applied to the RHS of `bash` variable assignments. Using `for f in $FILES` and `rm -- $FILES` works just fine (as long as `$FILES` is _unquoted_) - no need for an auxiliary array.

Comment: I have to admit that I ran the script with `sh mail2print.sh` instead of `bash mail2print.sh`. The use of `shopt` led me to this mistake. I'm still a beginner and learned my lesson for today ;)

Comment: @mklement0 I'm not sure about expanding filenames twice but that's not really bad and could be a preference sometimes. Perhaps during calls to `lpr` some rogue files may get generated and so your idea may give a benefit to it since they would also be deleted.

Comment: @konsolebox: Good point; thanks for explaining the difference.

Comment: Why not simply use `for f in /home/pi/attachments/*` or -- given that you delete all files at a later stage anyway -- `.../*.pdf`?

Comment: @tripleee Yes I guess that could be another way to it.

Answer (score -1):

Use below to filter the pdf files in the first place and then you can remove that if statement inside the for loop.

```
FILES="ls /home/pi/attachments/*.pdf"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that would leave non-pdf files undeleted in the ~/attachments/ folder.

Comment: Also assigning `ls` to the variable is hardly useful or correct. If the intent was to execute `ls` the syntax is incorrect, but it would be useless anyway.

Comment: @tripleee I agree that the syntax was incorrect for ls but I don't understand why it won't be "correct"?

Comment: In the best case, using `ls` to print the file names after the shell already expanded the wildcard is merely wasteful. In the worst case, there will be subdirectories, and `ls` will print their contents instead of their names, and so the output will be incorrect.